# Guess Numbers Based On Subsequence Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a SQL query to guess/identify a 9 digit number based on fuzzy subsequence input data.  The goal is to rank/sort the numbers based on fuzzy/weighted input scores for multiple subsequence possibilities.

I am having difficulty generating and sorting a large table of candidate numbers.

More specifically, using sqlfiddle.com I am so far unable to generate or sort a large table of 9 digit numbers.

I am encontering a timeout error before the Schema Build phase can complete.

Can anyone offer advice on how to generate and sort a large table using sqlfidde.com?

Here is the sqlfiddle link:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a15c9/3

And here is a copy of the exact code used in sqlfiddle:

Query Text:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (n INT);

INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (700000000),(700000001),(700000002),(700000003),(700000004);

INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;


ALTER TABLE numbers MODIFY COLUMN n TEXT;

CREATE TABLE ft (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, value TEXT NOT NULL, FULLTEXT KEY (value)) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO ft (value) SELECT * from numbers;
```

Query Text

```
/* Generate table of valid social security number ( SSN ) or valid social insurance number ( SIN ) for Canada. */

/* FIXME - Currently using small placeholder table that will work with SqlFiddle */

/* Sort social security number ( SSN ) based on audio queries */

SELECT   *,
match(value) against

  ('0*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

/* "AMERICA" query with weighted subsequences */
/* Default input weighting/score is 10.0 */

+ 10.0 * 1.0 * (value REGEXP '1776')
+ 10.0 * 2.0 * (value REGEXP '177')
+ 10.0 * 2.0 * (value REGEXP '776')
+ 10.0 * 3.0 * (value REGEXP '17')
+ 10.0 * 5.0 * (value REGEXP '77')
+ 10.0 * 3.0 * (value REGEXP '76')
+ 10.0 * 1.0 * (value REGEXP '7')
+ 10.0 * 1.0 * (value REGEXP '704')
+ 10.0 * 1.0 * (value REGEXP '0704')

/* "NICKELBACK" query with weighted subsequences */
/* Default input weighting/score is 2.0 */

+ 2.0 * 1.0 * (value REGEXP '..5..5..5')
+ 2.0 * 2.0 * (value REGEXP '..5..5...')
+ 2.0 * 3.0 * (value REGEXP '..5.....5')
+ 2.0 * 3.0 * (value REGEXP '.....5..5')
+ 2.0 * 4.0 * (value REGEXP '..5......')
+ 2.0 * 4.0 * (value REGEXP '.....5...')
+ 2.0 * 8.0 * (value REGEXP '........5')
+ 2.0 * 1.0 * (value REGEXP '5')

/* "AFGHANISTAN" query with weighted subsequences */
/* Default input weighting/score is 4.0 */

+ 4.0 * 2.0 * (value REGEXP '2003')
+ 4.0 * 2.0 * (value REGEXP '200')
+ 4.0 * 2.0 * (value REGEXP '003')
+ 4.0 * 3.0 * (value REGEXP '20')
+ 4.0 * 3.0 * (value REGEXP '03')
+ 4.0 * 4.0 * (value REGEXP '911')
+ 4.0 * 1.0 * (value REGEXP '91')
+ 4.0 * 2.0 * (value REGEXP '11')

/* 7 at start is stronly preferred */

+ 10000.0 * (value REGEXP '7........')

as score 
FROM ft
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

Here is the exact error I am encountering on sqlfiddle:

**Statement cancelled due to timeout or client request**

Comment: I just clicked your sqlfiddle link, pressed "Build Schema", then pressed "Run SQL" and it all worked. Am I missing a step?

Comment: sqlfiddle can sometimes fail for no reason. I've mostly switched to https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: I've had a similar issue other day - i'd use db-fiddle.com as @Barmar mentioned